# Why doesn't Ash swap out Pokémon more often?

Tags: character, pokemon

For example, in the XY Pokémon league when he was battling Shouta (I think that's his English name). Ash used Talonflame against a Water Type, leaving him at a type disadvantage, resulting in Talonflame fainting. Why didn't Ash switch to Pikachu when the Water Type Pokémon was sent out?

Why doesn't Ash switch Pokémon when a Pokémon with a Type advantage against his current Pokémon comes out?

Comment: This question is about playing strategy and not Moves & TV.

Comment: This question is about how a character acts in the freaking show.

Comment: Question is about playing strategy by a character in TV show. It seems on-topic to me

Comment: @Paulie_D question is still about the character analysis inside the show.

Answer (score 6):

- Ash has never been a very clever Pokémon Trainer
- Ash is very stubborn and will always keep fighting until his Pokémon is knocked out.
- Maybe the matches are lockdown (no switch) in the anime?
- Because Talonflame is his best friend and trusts him with his heart :D

Also that builds up suspense, so that Ash can bring out Pikachu as his very last Pokémon win against the odds.

Comment: In the Masters 8 episodes at the end of Pokemon Journeys, all of Ash's opponents switch out their Pokemon at some point, and everytime that happens, both Ash and Ash's friends all act surprised. That really makes it look like Ash is not aware of the strategic advantage that switching out a Pokemon can offer, and is always surprised when someone else does it.

Answer (score 1):

He often uses Pokémon that are at a type disadvantage, but he very often still wins. I mean he defeated a Snorlax with his Pikachu in the first episodes. Either he really doesn’t care about winning or losing, or he just really likes his Pokémon and wants them to have fun. He might also simply want a challenge. I mean for me in the Pokémon Games, it’s pretty boring when you have an OP Pokémon and beat everything with one hit. His Pikachu is also not his strongest Pokemon, yet he pretty much uses it in almost every battle at least once. If you wonder what Pokémon his strongest is, it’s Greninja in it’s “Ash Greninja” Form. His Charizard is also strong, because it was able to defeat a Dragonite. But that’s just me.